# 2592x1944 YUV422 one frame image size calculation issue

Tags: image-processing

I'd like to calculate 2592x1944 YUV422 one frame image size from camera.
I've already seen that https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV

But I'm not sure whether the below calculation is right or not.
and

```
YUV444    3 bytes per pixel     (12 bytes per 4 pixels)
YUV422    4 bytes per 2 pixels  ( 8 bytes per 4 pixels)
YUV411    6 bytes per 4 pixels
YUV420p   6 bytes per 4 pixels, reordered
```

with meaning of hsync length.

As I know, 2592x1944 YUV422 one frame image size which can be calculated such as

Total number of pixels in a frame = 2592*1944 = 5038848 Pixels

Total number of bytes in a frame = 5038848 *2=10077696 Bytes

Does it mean that 1 hsync real size(length)@ YUV422 is 2592*2  and changeable by YUV444, YUV422, YUV411, YUV420 ?

Answer (score 3):

Your calculation is right if we assume 8 bits color depth.

```
Y needs 2592x1944 x8bits    = 5038848 bytes
U needs 2592x1944 /2 x8bits = 2519424 bytes
V needs 2592x1944 /2 x8bits = 2519424 bytes
TOTAL = 10077696 bytes for YUV422, 8bits color
```

I don't get the question regarding hsync.

A nice explanation of YUV422 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7JYZDnenaGc,
and color depth https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bKjSox0uwnk.